# reorder a python list to match the order of another python list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
listA = ['market', 'fraud', 'crime', 'security', 'public', 
'state']

listB = ['security','fraud', 'state']
```

the elements present in `listB` needs to be in the same position of the elements of `listA`. If `listA` contains any element that `listB` does not contain, then I need to fill this empty position with the number `0`. So far, I only added the zeros to `listB` (see below). How can I achieve this goal?

```
difference = len(listA) - len(listB)
c= 0 
while c < b:
  c+=1
  listB.append(0)
```

my final output should look like:

```
listC = [0, 'fraud', 0, 'security', 0, 'state']
```

`listC` should contain `0` replacing the element that is not in `listB`. Strings that are present in `listB` should be in the `listC` in the same order (index position) they are in `listA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the new list from `listA`, but substitute `0` if items are not found in `listB`:

```py
listA = ['market', 'fraud', 'crime', 'security', 'public', 'state']

listB = ['security','fraud', 'state']

listC = [item if item in listB else 0 for item in listA]
print(listC)
```

Output as requested

*Update:*

As Mark Ransom points out, if `listB` is very large, it would be more efficient to search through a set of those elements:

```py
listA = ['market', 'fraud', 'crime', 'security', 'public', 'state']

listB = ['security','fraud', 'state']
slistB = set(listB)

listC = [item if item in slistB else 0 for item in listA]
print(listC)
```

Same output

Comment: If `listB` is large it would be helpful to make a `set` from it for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

the other solution is correct here's another simpler format:

```
listA = ['market', 'fraud', 'crime', 'security', 'public', 
'state']

listB = ['security','fraud', 'state']
listC=[]
for i in listA:
    if i in listB:
        listC.append(i)
    else:
        listC.append('0')
        
print(listC)
```